# How to get active directory department user property in a column?

Tags: document-library, active-directory, user-profile-property, sharepoint-on-prem

I've got a document library and want to add the department filled from AD, so the library can be sorted by department. How can I do this?

I tried to add column of type "**Person or group**" and show field "**department**". It is not filled

Comment: Could you pls check if department property is mapped to AD field or not in central admin?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

I get the department with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetCurrentUser() {

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccessA,
  error : onErrorA
});
}

function onSuccessA(data, request){

    // alert("Success One");
    // cutting of i:0#.w|

    //console.log(data.d);
    //var emailAdresse = data.d.Email;
    //alert(emailAdresse);

    var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];

    var repOne = "%5C";  
    var repTwo = "%2E";
    // alert("before replace: " + loginName);

    loginName = loginName.replace(/\\/g, repOne); // replace \ with %5C
    loginName = loginName.replace(/\./g, repTwo); // replace . with %2E

    // alert("after replace: " + loginName);

    GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginName); // call next function to get department. Pass the loginname into the function
}

function onErrorA(error) {

  alert(error);
}

GetCurrentUser();

});

function GetCurrentUserDepartment(loginNameAcc) {
// alert("LoginName: " + loginNameAcc)
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Department')?@v=" + "'" + loginNameAcc + "'";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  method: "GET",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccessB,
  error : onErrorB
});
}

function onSuccessB(data){

    //do someting

}

function onErrorB(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        alert("Error: " + jqxr.responseText)
}

</script>
```

I am using this, to set a link on the startpage to the specific department teamsite.

Hope this will help.

Comment: can this code be put into calculated column ? or so.
As i'm not allowed to use visual studio here to "program" against sharepoint.

As if possible i hope above code would fill Department once (upon creation), of the document, and wont change as document property if someone changes deparment (promotion) or so.

Comment: You can add an script editor webpart or an content editor webpart and paste the code inside of that. Please also check the mentioned link.

Comment: For setting metadata in documents you can use a workflow which runs on item creation or change for a specific content type. That could solve that.

Comment: I'm trying with sharepoint designer, but no luck either.
I am using set field (my department column) to to the person who created this item, and from that userprofile retrieve Department.

Doesnt work either

Comment: Are you getting the department via the rest url? Then you should be able to get it in an SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

Comment: No, i dont have options to use http requests in sharepoint designer

Comment: apparently sharepoint 2013 workflows are not installed, its using the 2010 engine